# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

here's my piece of code. when i execute i get an error as give below

```
If Val(dr("USE_Amount").ToString) >= Val(txtprice.Text) Then
                    dr.Close()
                    msg = "Ref No : " + ref_no + ". Your mobile no : " + txt_mob.Text + " Talk time : " + txttalk.Text + " Validity : " + txtval.Text
                    cmd = New SqlCommand("update TBL_Banking set USE_Amount=USE_Amount-" + txtprice.Text + " where USE_creditcard='" + txt_credit.Text + "' and USE_pin='" + txt_pwd.Text + "' and USE_uname='" + HiddenField1.Value + "' and USE_Bank='" + ddl_bank.SelectedItem.Text + "'", con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into TBL_Recharge values('" + Now.ToString + "','" + txt_mob.Text + "','" + dvendor.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + txt_credit.Text + "','" + ddl_bank.SelectedItem.Text + "'," + txtprice.Text + ",'" + HiddenField1.Value + "','" + msg + "')", con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            lbl_msg.Text = "Recharge sucessfully"

            MsgBox("Recharge Message Successfully send to mobile no : " + txt_mob.Text)
            txt_mob.Text = ""
            txt_credit.Text = ""
            txt_pwd.Text = ""
            txt_pwd.Text = ""
        Else
            dr.Close()
            lbl_msg.Text = "Unable to Recharge..Invalid Balance"
        End If
```

the error message is `string or binary data would be truncated.`

Comment: Can you please post your table schema for TBL_Recharge.

Answer (score 2):

Basically,  one of the insert value's size exceeds its respective column's size. Also, you should use parameterized query, otherwise:-
1) your code will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks, and
2) certain characters in the textboxes will give you exception. For example, try writing "abc'd" in your txt_mob.

Answer (score 1):

the error `String or binary data would be truncated` occurs when you try to insert some value to a database column with length of data more than the actual column length or capacity.ie if we insert a string with 51 characters to a column with maximum length 50,same error occurs.

check for the same scenario in your database.